# My code doesn't do anything. What could be the reason?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

Vue component not rendering and no error, But it loads the vue cdn.
Nothing is in place of the component.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head> 
  <title>Vue</title>
</head>
<body>  


      <blog-post :title="My journey with Vue"></blog-post>
      <blog-post v-bind:title="Blogging with Vue"></blog-post>
      <blog-post title="Why Vue is so fun"></blog-post>



  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/v`enter code here`ue.js"></script>
  <script>

    Vue.component('blog-post', {
      props: ['title'],
      template: '<div><h3>{{ title }}</h3></div>'
    })

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: URL of script load has the `\`enter code here`\` sub string inserted in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should create a Vue instance and bind it an element
2. Where strings are passed literally to the `title` prop, remove `:` before the binding. In this way Vue will not try to evaluate them as expressions

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head> 
  <title>Vue</title>
</head>
<body>  

     <div id="app">
      <blog-post title="My journey with Vue"></blog-post>
      <blog-post title="Blogging with Vue"></blog-post>
      <blog-post title="Why Vue is so fun"></blog-post>
     </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
  <script>
    Vue.component('blog-post', {
      props: ['title'],
      template: '<div><h3>{{ title }}</h3></div>'
    });
    
    new Vue({
      el: '#app'
    });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```